# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent hasOne relationship doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have relationship in my chat model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::class,'id','writers_id');
}
```

And want to use it in my controller. I tryed many ways, but no one worked. Just giving last try example (result - blank page).

```
print_r($chat = Chat::where('id', 1)->first()->user);
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks! I don't really understand that Eloquent, used simple DB query maker before, however someone said that I should do every database stuff in model. Is it correct? Sorry about my poor English!

Comment: Check the order of parameters: `$this->hasOne('App\ModelName', 'foreign_key', 'local_key')`

Comment: id is id in user table, writers_id is in chat table, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. Swap the 2 parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as mentioned by @Vohuman

```
return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'writers_id');
```

And when using it:

```
Chat::where('id', 1)->first()->user()->first()->attribute
```

Comment: If you pass it to a variable you can do whatever you want. Like `$chat = Chat::where('id', 1)->first()` then `$chat->attribute` or `$chat->user()->first()->attribute`

Comment: by the way, is it really better to do everything with model than with query builder?

Comment: Yes, definitely. You should, in my opinion, always work with your models if possible

Comment: but why it is better?

Comment: It's a question of structure and efficiency. Laravel itself follow the traditional MVC-pattern (Model, View, Controller) and to make it easier for you not to end up with unstructured code where strange errors easy occur and solutions for sometimes easy problems will be much more hard to find. The Eloquent ORM is already super efficient with its functions to communicate with the database, set up datasets and so on. It's a bad choice to reinvent the wheel again and not use what's already been developed and tested.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

In `App\Chat.php`:

```
public function writer()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User','id','writers_id');
}
```

to define the relation. Then in whatever controller:

At top:

```
use App\User;
```

and inside the method:

```
$writer = User::find($user_id)->writer;
```

to debug it add one line in front of the above line.

```
dd($user_id,User::find($user_id),$writer);
```